# Trying to write a WHERE LIKE statement with AND *and* OR

Tags: sql, postgresql

I seem to not be able to find this question, just iterations of it. So here we go:

I'm trying to write this (note the +* is for explanation)

```
SELECT column FROM table
WHERE column LIKE '[REQUIRED STRING]' [??] 'POSSIBLE STRING_A' OR 'POSSIBLE STRING_B'...etc
```

- basically, my problem is I either return *ONLY* the REQUIRED STRING (which is not helpful) *OR* REQUIRED STRING + 1 of the possible strings (usually the first one) when I want the option of returning all of the options (eg, REQUIRED STRING + POSSIBLE STRING_B; REQUIRED STRING + POSSIBLE STRING_X, etc.)

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 1):

"column" and LIKE must be repeated each time.  They will not be *just understood* to be there, like might happen in human speech.

```
"column" LIKE 'required' AND ("column" LIKE 'option1' OR "column" LIKE 'option2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rather lacking in details, seems you forgot the +* explanation, and missing all sample data and table description. So I make a couple assumptions. You are looking for a specific sub-string and at least 1 of the specified sub-strings all within a single column. Second, since you are trying to emulate `LIKE` the specified strings must appear as specified but can have leading and/or trailing components, similar to `%sub-string%`. So that is exactly what it does. The technique will be to create an array out of the optional strings when `UNNEST` it, also take care of the case of there not being any optional values. So:  (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f94229a96c27bdb8e4b2eff314c09d85))

```
create or replace 
function like_with_and_or(
         required_string text 
       , optional_strigs text[] 
       )
  returns setof mtable
  language sql 
as $$
   select * 
     from mtable mt  
     where mt.col1 like '%' || required_string ||  '%'
       and (   array_ndims(optional_strigs) is null     -- no optional_strigs
            or exists ( select null
                          from unnest(optional_strigs) os
                         where mt.col1 like '%' || os ||  '%' 
                      ) 
           );
$$;
```